# Many class, one train sample per class classification

Tags: machine-learning, classification, k-nearest-neighbour

I have a classification task involving one train sample per class with around 300 classes.Furthermore each observasion has about 200 features. Can anyone suggest an approach that might work better than 1 nearest neighbor?

Comment: Why do you have 300 classes? Can't you reduce those?

Answer (score 1):

You can't really do it like that. 1 sample per class brings no information at all about the joint probability of that class on feature space.